# SQL Server Stored Procedure IF Exist Update Else Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

I created a stored procedure locally (IF Exist Update Else Insert)

When I execute the procedure it can't insert or update any data, SQL Server shows that query has run successfully.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Laptops 
(
    Brand varchar(50),
    Series varchar(50),
    Model varchar(50),
    Gener int,
    Ram int,
    HDD int,
    Processor varchar(50),
    Clock float,
    Graphic_Chip varchar(50),
    Graphic_Memory int,
    Qty int,
    Price int
    PRIMARY KEY (Brand,Series,Model,Gener,Ram,HDD,Processor,Clock,Graphic_Chip,Graphic_Memory)
)
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Insert_Inventory
(
    @Brand Varchar(50),
    @Series Varchar(50),
    @Model Varchar(50),
    @Gener int,
    @Ram int,
    @HDD int,
    @Processor Varchar(50),
    @Clock float,
    @Graphic_Chip Varchar(50),
    @Graphic_Memory int,
    @Qty int,
    @Price int
)
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Laptops
               WHERE Brand = @Brand
                 and Series = @Series
                 and Model = @Model
                 and Gener = @Gener 
                 and ram = @Ram 
                 and hdd = @HDD 
                 and Processor = @Processor 
                 and Clock = @Clock 
                 and Graphic_Chip = @Graphic_Chip 
                 and Graphic_Memory = @Graphic_Memory)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Laptops 
        SET 
            Qty = Qty + @Qty, 
            Price = @Price
        WHERE 
            Brand = @Brand 
            and Series = @Series
            and Model = @Model 
            and Gener = @Gener 
            and ram = @Ram 
            and hdd = @HDD 
            and Processor = @Processor 
            and Clock = @Clock 
            and Graphic_Chip = @Graphic_Chip 
            and Graphic_Memory = @Graphic_Memory
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
       INSERT into Laptops 
       VALUES (@Brand, @Series, @Model, @Gener, @Ram, @HDD, @Processor, @Clock, @Graphic_Chip, @Graphic_Memory, @Qty, @Price)
    END
```

Execute

```
exec Insert_Inventory 'Dell', 'Inspiron', '14', 3, 4, 500, 'Core_i_5', 2.7, 'NVIDIA', 512, 20, 42000
```

Comment: It works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a34d0/2

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to wrap your SP into `BEGIN` & `END`, you are missing that. And also use 1 when check `IF Exist` in `Select Statement`.And also check that, Some transaction is open but not commit. Instead of Doing this also, You can use SQL MERGE to Update and Insert Statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Insert_Inventory
(
    @Brand Varchar(50),
    @Series Varchar(50),
    @Model Varchar(50),
    @Gener int,
    @Ram int,
    @HDD int,
    @Processor Varchar(50),
    @Clock float,
    @Graphic_Chip Varchar(50),
    @Graphic_Memory int,
    @Qty int,
    @Price int
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Laptops
        WHERE Brand=@Brand
            and Series=@Series
            and Model=@Model
            and Gener=@Gener 
            and ram=@Ram 
            and hdd=@HDD 
            and Processor=@Processor 
            and Clock=@Clock 
            and Graphic_Chip=@Graphic_Chip 
            and Graphic_Memory=@Graphic_Memory
    )
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Laptops set qty=qty+@Qty, Price=@Price
        WHERE Brand=@Brand 
            and Series=@Series
            and Model=@Model 
            and Gener=@Gener 
            and ram=@Ram 
            and hdd=@HDD 
            and Processor=@Processor 
            and Clock=@Clock 
            and Graphic_Chip=@Graphic_Chip 
            and Graphic_Memory=@Graphic_Memory
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT into Laptops Values (@Brand,@Series,@Model,@Gener,@Ram,@HDD,@Processor,@Clock,@Graphic_Chip,@Graphic_Memory,@Qty,@Price)
    END

END
```

Comment: FYI - **One or more Transact-SQL** statements comprising the body of the procedure. You can use the optional BEGIN and END keywords to enclose the statements check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx for more info

Comment: Actually the original code posted by Khurram works. The BEGIN END is optional.